# Using the same hotkey for two different purposes in Python

Tags: python, keyboard

Using pythons keyboard library,
I have two function definitions:

```
def start_tracking():
 *code to start tracking time*

def end_tracking():
 *code to stop tracking time*
```

I then want to use the same hotkey (e.g. F1) to invoke function 1 (start tracking time) on the first press and then function 2 (end tracking time) on the subsequent press. If I press the hotkey again after that, it should repeat the process.

Basically I want to use the same hotkey to track time and stop tracking time.

Here's what a working solution to start tracking time and stop tracking time **using two different hotkeys** looks like:

```
keyboard.add_hotkey("F1", start_tracking)
keyboard.add_hotkey("F2", end_tracking)
```

How can I accomplish the same thing with only one key (F1)?
I don't want to use a while loop because it slows down performance quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a class variable or global variable as a flag. Such that:

```
class tracker():

    def __init__(self):
        self.start_flag = True <- Init class variable

    def tracking(self):

         if self.start_flag:
              start_tracking()
              self.start_flag = False #<- class variable toggling
         else:
              stop_tracking()
              self.start_flag = True #<- class variable toggling


if name == '__main__'
     x = tracker()
     x.tracking() # starts tracker 
     time.sleep(5)
     x.tracking() # stops tracker
```

Without more context on what your program is doing I can't say which is better. Typically globals should be avoided though. Simply put, you need a way to toggle which function is run. PS copypasting wont work. You will need to setup the class etc for proper usage. especially with where and how you defined start/stop. I would guess you are using globals but typically this should be avoided.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to implement your solution and learn about flags. In the meantime I came up with my own one, see answer below:

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
def started():
    start_tracking()
    keyboard.remove_hotkey("F1")
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F1", ended)

def ended():
    end_tracking()
    keyboard.remove_hotkey("F1")
    keyboard.add_hotkey("F1", started)

#Hotkey

keyboard.add_hotkey("F1", started)
```

Basically I switch between the two events every time I press the hotkey by calling two functions in an alternating fashion.

Comment: Good way to go. But depending on how long start/end_tracking() function runs, your F1 key might not work. Not an issue if it isnt an issue though.